# Навигация между страницами в Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, bottom-navigation-view

Такая проблема: пишу приложение на Xamarin Forms.
Логика такая: есть главная страница (contentPage), при нажатии на кнопку "Смотреть", должен быть осуществлен переход на страницу (Shell) с нижним меню, однако при использовании кода ниже страницы наслаиваются друг на друга:

```
// Кнопка "Смотреть"
private async void LoadBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
     // App.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
}
```

Если же вторую строчку в методе активировать, проблемы не возникает, однако в таком случае переход некий обрывистый, выглядит не очень.

В связи с этим вопрос: **можно ли сделать допустим анимацию загрузки (кастомную или встроенную) при переходе между страницами и использовать её для решения данной проблемы или нет?**